# To distribute to people according to percentage values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, algorithm, python-2.7

I have an algorithm that I want to create. The structure of this algorithm should be as follows. Below is a CSV file defined in the code block. In this file, each customer has specific weights. The sum of these weights is 100%.

```
Customer,Weight

A,3.39
B,0.86
C,0.060000000000002274
D,1.43
E,24.66
F,0.34
G,24.49
H,7.59
I,7.24
J,25.58
K,3.96
L,0.4
```

My Goal:

For example, let's say there are 3 people. When I want to distribute the customers equally to these 3 people, each person gets a 33% share. These share values ​​are obtained from the values ​​of the customers listed above. How can I distribute these values ​​equally to people?

[image]

My Opinion:

I'm on the side of using a library like Pandas in Python to make this allocation. But I have no idea yet how to create it. It would be great for me if you could share a code sample or source for this algorithm. Thank you very much in advance for your help.

What I've Tried:

I made operations with many parameters of the Pandas library in Python. But I'm new to Python and just getting used to using these libraries. Because of this, I couldn't do much.

Comment: It's not an easy problem, and apparently there might not be a solution/partition, even with some threshold. For example, [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-to-k-equal-sum-subsets/) is a similar problem for list of integers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the classic optimization problem [Bin packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).

You can use [linear solver approach](https://developers.google.com/optimization/pack/bin_packing) or you can use existing python packages for this exact task, most notably [numberpartitioning](https://github.com/fuglede/numberpartitioning) or a wrapper around it like [binpacking](https://github.com/benmaier/binpacking).

```
$ pip install binpacking
```

```
>>> import binpacking

>>> b = {'A': 3.39, 'B': 0.86, 'C': 0.060000000000002274,
         'D': 1.43, 'E': 24.66, 'F': 0.34, 'G': 24.49,
         'H': 7.59, 'I': 7.24, 'J': 25.58, 'K': 3.96, 'L': 0.4}
>>> bins = binpacking.to_constant_bin_number(b, 3)
>>> bins
[{'J': 25.58, 'K': 3.96, 'A': 3.39, 'L': 0.4},
 {'E': 24.66, 'I': 7.24, 'D': 1.43},
 {'G': 24.49, 'H': 7.59, 'B': 0.86, 'F': 0.34, 'C': 0.060000000000002274}]
```